How to atomically exchange an executable that could be invoked at any time
We have a service on our server that is triggered by a cronjob quite frequently. Now we want to update this application to a new version.
How can we do so without risking the application to be in an invalid state, e.g. if I unlink it first (as described in Replacing a running executable in linux) and then rename the new application to the filename that will be invoked by cron, there's always the risk that I'm in this "inbetween" state where the old application is unlinked and not visible anymore and the new application is not yet renamed and thus cannot be found by cron.
How do I accomplish this on RHEL and debian linux?

You don't need to unlink the old binary first. Just mv new_version old_verison. Rename is atomic in Linux, so your cron job will either execute the old version or the new version.
